# How to remove that ugly border in my link with a background image?

Tags: html, css, image, border, hyperlink

I'm making a navigation menu with background images. I managed to vanish the text with text-indent, but it shows a very ugly border while clicking the link. How do I get rid of the border? My css is gven below;

```
       #menu{
  width:670px;
  float:right;
      }

    #menu ul{
    padding-top:10px;
     }
      #menu ul li{
        list-style-type:none;
     display: block;
      float:left;
    width:163px;
     height:270px;
     }

   #menu ul li a{
   height:270px;
    display: block;
    width:163px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:none;
      }
     .box_1{
      background: url(images/box_1.png) no-repeat;
      width:163px;
     height:268px;
     border:none;
     }

     .box_2{
    background: url(images/box_2.png) no-repeat;
    width:163px;
    height:268px;
    border:none;
       }

    .box_3{
     background: url(images/box_3.png) no-repeat;
     width:163px;
    height:268px;
    border:none;
     }

     .box_4{
     background: url(images/box_4.png) no-repeat;
     width:163px;
     height:268px;
     border:none;
     }
```

And my html:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a class="box_1" href="#">creative solutions</a></li>
 <li><a class="box_2" href="#">dynamic development</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="box_3">unlimited opportunities</a></li>
 <li><a  class="box_4" href=#">exceptional approach</a></li></ul>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance for helping!!

Comment: Erm, please don't remove that. That's how I know that a particular link currently has the focus.

Comment: umm... it appears throughout the whole screen, looks very bad!! sorry!

Comment: I think there are 2 situations whether to remove it or not:  (1) if it is clicking on the website logo, going to the homepage of the site, and the user clicks "Back", then the logo can have the dotted outline and it can look ugly, in that case it can be considered to be removed.  (2) if it is a long list of items, that's true, I do hope to see what I clicked before, so as a user, I would rather it stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply another css style:

```
#menu ul li a:active {
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: @Snowbell92 - Awesome :) Don't forget to click the check mark to identify it. I see you have a couple of other questions that have not had answers identified, and pretty soon it'll show your acceptance rating when you post questions.

Answer (score 9):

You mean the dotted outline? Remove it like this:

```
a {
   outline: 0;
}
```

You may want to add an alternative focus style. See [here](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/).

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? You're not talking about img border are you? img { border: none; }

Comment: no, ofcourse not. I'm talking about the border it gets while the link has focus. setting outline didn't work, but when I set a:active to border:none., it worked!

Comment: Does it also work setting a:active { outline:0; } ? Perhaps we are talking about different borders.

Answer (score 1):

The dotted line thing?

`a {outline:0}`

Comment: Hi, yes, the dotted thing.I tried setting outline, but not working!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are talking about ugly dotted border that is shown up when the element (in your case image) receives focus (by click or by pressing tab).

Use css property:

```
outline: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line on the top of your css file,

```
* :focus { outline: 0; }
```